# Command that prints file contents given filename on stdin

Tags: cat, xargs, stdin

I have a command that produces some output part of which is actually a file name containing the full output data.  I want to extract the file name (which I trivially do with `cut`) and then pass it to another program such as `cat` which will display the contents of that file.

I can't share the actual command I am running but for the purposes of reproducibility you can replace `./my-command args` with `echo 1:2:3:4:file.txt`

So I tried the following:

```
./my-command args | cut -d : -f 5 | cat
```

However this just prints the file name since `cat` merely copies the contents of stdin (which contains my filename) to stdout when it is invoked without any arguments.

Now I know that I can work around this is Bash by inverting the flow of commands and essentially passing `cat` the argument via a sub-shell e.g.

```
cat `./my-command args | cut -d : -f 5`
```

And this will print the contents of the file however this is not particularly friendly since I can't simply pipe the output of my underlying command by appending a simple command to my invocation.

Is there a `cat` like program which will take in filenames on stdin and print their contents?  Or is there a way to get `cat` to treat stdin as arguments?

#### Notes

I realise that I could define a bash function that would read filenames from stdin and invoke `cat` on them in my own environment.  However this technique for dumping the output data directly needs to be included in end user documentation and a simple shell agnostic approach is highly preferable.

Answer (score 7):

After doing a bit more research I realised that this scenario is exactly what [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) is designed for:

```
./my-command args | cut -d : -f 5 | xargs cat
```

Which will transform the output of stdin into an invocation of `cat` with an actual filename and thus print out the file contents

Comment: That assumes the file name doesn't contain space, tab, single quote, double quote or backslash characters though (and newline, but your usage of `cut` already seems to imply that) (and other blank characters in your locale with some `xargs` implementations). With GNU `xargs`, you can use `xargs -rd '\n' cat` to assume a newline delimited list of files.